# Generate smart contract wrapper for android app

Tags: contract-invocation

I've downloaded command line tool for generating smart contract wrapper.I put my compiled contract into `out` folder near web3j.bat file.However when I run this command
`web3j solidity generate ./out/test_sol_TestToken.bin ./out/test_sol_TestToken.abi -o D:\android_dev\projects\eth_test\app\src\main\java -p test.user`
I got this error

```
D:\Desktop\web3\bin>web3j solidity generate ./out/test_sol_TestToken.bin ./out/t
est_sol_TestToken.abi -o D:\android_dev\projects\eth_test\app\src\main\java -p t
est.user
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/web3j/con
sole/Runner : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

It looks like I have incorrect jdk version. I tried to add system env variable
`JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7` with no luck.Can someone point me which jdk version web3j requires?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like web3 requires jre8+.It created wrapper class after I updated jre and changed JAVA_HOME